# A more specific welcome message?

Tags: discussion, user-interface

The welcome message in the sidebar says currently:

> This is a collaboratively edited question and answer site for WordPress developers and administrators. It's 100% free, no registration required.
>
> Got a question about the site itself? meta is the place to talk about things like what questions are appropriate, what tags we should use, etc.

[image]

The problem is: WordPress developers **do** talk about JavaScript, CSS and PHP. The message describes our intended audience, not what is on topic.

Should we change that to help new users to decide if their question is on topic here?

Suggestion for the first sentence (please improve, English is not my native language):

> This is a collaboratively edited question and answer site about WordPress development and administration.

Comment: How about `development and administration` ? Your site accepts questions on *using* WordPress as much as building infrastructure within its context.

Comment: @Aarthi You're right, I changed my suggestion.

Comment: @Aarthi Any progress? What makes this so hard?

Comment: Honestly, toscho, this proposal doesn't seem to have gotten a lot of traction from the community. +4 in almost a year doesn't seem like this is a real problem your users are facing

Comment: @Aarthi snippets like this are editable by moderators in FAQ and new about page, why not in this block?

Comment: @Aarthi Because we're more focused on the actual site on don't look on meta on a day-to-day basis. It got my support now. Upvoted.

Comment: @Rarst Mostly because that box is populated from text from the audience description used elsewhere.